# Remove dynamically added css from <head>

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-head

On button click, I'm adding a css to the `<head>`:

```
$("head").append("<link id='#color_1_css' href='" + newCssHref +"' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
```

which adds to `<head>`:

```
<link id="#color_1_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/styles/colors/f69548/f69548.css">
```

On another button click I need to remove it again. I tried the following, which doesn't work for some reason:

```
   $('html').on('click', '.clear-color-picker', function(events){
           var id = $(this).attr('data-parentID').replace('background_color','');
           $('#' + $(this).attr('data-parentID')).setColor('');
           $('#' + id).css('background-color','');

           if (id == 'main-color') {
                console.log('clicked');
                $('#color_1_css').remove();
            }
   })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did it produce any errors?

Comment: No, it just doesn't remove the style for some reason...

Comment: <link id="#color_1_css" should be <link id="color_1_css"

Answer (score 5):

Because your id starts with `#`?

Answer (score 4):

Your ID is incorrect:

```
$("head").append("<link id='#color_1_css'
                            ^---
```

It should be `id='color_1_css'`, or you use `$('##color_1_css')` instead

Comment: *"or you use `$('##color_1_css')` instead"* No, you can't, you'd have to escape the second `#`.